# how to get matching objects array of objects and json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my object.I need to access only "oname": "Fon" and "bid": 1 object details. There is no need to access "bid": "2" object details

```js
{
    "oid": "1",
    "oname": "Fon",
    "bun": [{
        "bid": "1",
        "bname": "Ets",
        "dep": [{
            "did": "1",
            "dname": "Dptment",
            "pids": [{
                "pid": "1",
                "st": "active"
            }, {
                "pid": "2",
                "st": "active"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "bid": "2",
        "bname": "US",
        "description": "unit2",
        "dep": []
    }]
}
```

Comment: probably make use of filter

Comment: I'm not sure I understand whats being asked here... Use dot notation? `object.oname` and `object.bun[0].bid`

Comment: Something like this, https://jsfiddle.net/ctwhhko7/

Comment: bun.filter(function (obj) {
                    return (obj.bid == 1); using this only get "bid": "1" object details correctly but i want "oname": "Fon" also

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method to get desired data

```
 var arr = {
            "oid": "1",
            "oname": "Fon",
            "bun": [{
                "bid": "1",
                "bname": "Ets",
                "dep": [{
                    "did": "1",
                    "dname": "Dptment",
                    "pids": [{
                        "pid": "1",
                        "st": "active"
                    }, {
                        "pid": "2",
                        "st": "active"
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                "bid": "2",
                "bname": "US",
                "description": "unit2",
                "dep": []
            }]
        }

var oname = arr.oname;
var data = arr.bun.filter(function (a) { return a.bid == "1" });
```

Comment: :i need oname and bid="1" objcet details are in single objct how it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to get a subset of only the data you want:

```
data.bun.filter(function(d){ if( d.bid == 1 ) return true; } );
```

---

#### Create a new object with the data you wish to have

```
var newObj = {
   "oname": data.oname, 
   "bun": data.bun.filter(function(d){ if( d.bid == 1 ) return true; } ) 
};
```

Comment: @it only get bid==1 object  details i need "oname": "Fon" also  on the result

Comment: @SHERINAS That data is accessible via: `data.oname`.  Check my snippet again to see how you might create a new object with both keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bracket notation in javascript for this like

```
var key = "oname";
var value = json[key];
```